# How do I integrate a 3rd party api on a wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I need to integrate a 3rd party API with a website and I have no idea where to even start. I just have this endpoint-
GET Current Occupancy
[https://api.abcfinancial.com/rest/{clubNumber}/clubs/checkins/occupancy](https://api.abcfinancial.com/rest/%7BclubNumber%7D/clubs/checkins/occupancy)
currentOccupancy Returns the current number of members in the club.
maxOccupancy Returns the maximum number of members allowed in the club.
currentOccupancyPercentage Returns the current percentage of members in the club.

I need to get the current occupancy and show it on the slider revolution slide. Any help of how to do this or anything would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly. When asking a question it is better to show what research you have done into your problem and post any code or errors if it applies.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to use it specifically on the front end, you can look to implement the API call using Javascript. Using the [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) API would work in that case. You would look to add the script and enqueue it within your `functions.php` file.

If you need to do it on the server side, you can use either [cURL](https://codular.com/curl-with-php) or `get_file_contents` to access the API.

With the server side option, the page will generally take longer to load as you are not getting back a response to the your site until the server has hit your API. With the Javascript option, you can look to hit the API without blocking the rest of your page.